# Bartlett pears are all shaped like apples this year

Tags: diagnosis

This year for the first time all the pears on my 13 year old Bartlett pear tree are in the shape of round apples I am in South Carolina. Is this some sort of a deficiency. The tree looks normal. And the fruit has always been pear shaped until this season. What is wrong?[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

What you have on the pictures actually looks like nashi (asian pear) which has the shape of an apple and the color and texture (and internal structure) of a pear. Your fruit tree is almost certainly a grafted tree where a desired pear cultivar has been grafted onto the root stock of a different species (for its more resilient and efficient rooting system for instance). And if a nashi's been used as a root stock it might explain this strange phenomenon. A drafted tree is basically a chimera i.e. a single organism with distinct set(s) of cells. And these two organisms interact in some way with each other and every once in a while might produce spectacular results like this.